# Log parser Query parameter values containing spaces

Tags: logparser

Log parser allows us to query though .sql file and also accepts the parameters, but the problem is how to supply the parameter values containing spaces in them.

eg. logparser file:filename.sql?param1=data+param2=C:\Program Files\Folder Name\file.txt

here param2 value contains spaces, how to successfully pass these values to log parser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enclose the entire argument in double-quote characters. For example:

```
logparser "file:filename.sql?param1=data+param2=C:\Program Files\Folder Name\file.txt"
```

Comment: Double-quotes are not working..i have already tried both single and double quote characters.

Comment: Then the problem is apparently in your SQL query, where param2 is replaced. In that case enclose the value of param2 within single quotes: logparser "file:filename.sql?param1=data+param2='C:\Program Files\Folder Name\file.txt'" (note how the command ends with a single quote followed by a double quote character).

Comment: Thank you.! Got the results.!

One more problem - log parser allows us to directly insert the results in a sql server..is there any way that we can also process that result to extract some information. Like to get the max of a column.

Comment: Unfortunately, no. But you can first write the results to, say, a temporary CSV file and *then* import that CSV file into a database.

Comment: If you pass the parameter as a variable in PowerShell, in the LogParser string encapsulated with double quotes, you will need to put single quotes around the variable.
`$SearchLocation = "C:\Program Files\Folder Name\file.txt"`
`.\LogParser.exe -i:W3C "$LogInformation FROM '$SearchLocation' WHERE $IISSearchParam GROUP BY $OutPutParam" -o:csv`